# Find the equation of the plane that passes through a point and parallel to another plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the plane given that it passes through the point $P = (0, -2, 5)$ and parallel to the plane $6x - y + 2z = 3$.

If we're given $P$ in the equation is

$$n \cdot r = n \cdot p$$

where $r = (x,y,z)$. However, if I take the vector from the general form and substitute it in for n, it doesn't make sense. <6,-1,2> Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you've described the problem correctly? The given point $P$ does not lie in the given plane. Is the plane you want supposed to be parallel to the given one?

Comment: @JohnHabert Sorry, I mixed up two problems.

Comment: there infinite number of such lines, i think some thing is still wrong

Comment: The problem states - Find the normal form of the equation of the plane that passes through P and is parallel to the general equation.

Comment: The normal of the plane is the coefficients as $n=(6,-1,2)$

Comment: The title says _find the line_ and the statement says _find the plane_. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have plane normal direction vector of $$\vec{n} = (6,-1,2)/|(6,-1,2)| =\frac{1}{\sqrt{46}} (6,-2,2)$$ and the distance of the plane to the origin $$d = 3/|\vec{n}|=\frac{3}{\sqrt{46}}$$

The new plane normal is identical to $\vec{n}$ and the new distance is

$$ r = \vec{n}\cdot\vec{p} = \frac{17}{\sqrt{46}}  $$

So your plane is

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{46}} (6,-1,3).(x,y,z) - r = 0 $$
  $$ 6x-y+3z-17 =0 $$

Comment: Why would you find distances? You can just substitute into the formula given in the OP and get the answer.

Comment: For completeness. In order to understand how to go from $A x+B y+C z = D$ to planar normal and location and back.

Comment: $\vec{n} = (6,-1,2)/|(6,-1,2)| =\frac{1}{\sqrt{41}} (6,-1,2)$

Comment: Fat fingered a $2$ in there I guess. Since it is accepted and the method is valid, I am unsure if I should edit and change all the numbers around. 3 years in the wrong already.

Comment: The planes' normals will be the same because they are parallel. $6x-y+2z=-12$