# How do I find the equation of the plane through the origin that is parallel to the plane?

Tags: vectors

Plane = $4x-2y+7z+12=0$

How do I find the equation of the plane through the origin that is parallel to the plane?

Comment: @SarGe nope. I have no idea what that means

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/664884) may help you. Also, first check whether a similar question exist in the system which can help you before posting a new one.

Comment: @SarGe Thanks dude. Appreciate ur help

Answer (score 1):

The normal vector to your given plane is $(4,-2,7)$.  Any plane parallel to your given plane will have the same normal vector.  Can you find a plane with this normal vector that contains the origin?

Answer (score 0):

To every plane you can associate a normal vector $\vec n$, that is, a vector that is perpendicular to the plane. The trick is to realize that if there is a vector $\vec v$ in the plane then the angle between the two vectors is $90^o$. This means that $\vec n\cdot\vec v=0$ for any vector $\vec v$ in the plane.

If $\vec n=(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ and $\vec v=(x,y,z)$ is any vector then the vector is inside the plane, associated to $\vec n$, if and only if $$\vec n\cdot \vec v=n_1x+n_2y+n_3z=0$$

[image]

**Hint**:

- If two planes are parallel, what do they have in common?
- You are given the plane $$4x-2y+7x+12=0$$ How would you check whether, say the point $(-3,0,0)$ is inside it? Now, what about $(0,0,0)$?